# Insert id value to another id jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.neigborhood').click(function() {
    var neigborhood_child = $(this).children();
    var neigborhood_id = $(neigborhood_child).val();
    var img = $('.img').val(neigborhood_id);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<span id="<?php echo "neigborhood_".$neigborhood_id;?>" href="" class="neigborhood fake-link">
      <input type="hidden" id="neigborhood" value="<?php echo $neigborhood_id;?>">
      <?php  echo $neigborhood_title ?>
    </span>
    <li id="<?php echo $neigborhood_id;?>">
      <a href="<?php echo "hotels/".$hotel_alias; ?>" title="<?php echo $hotel_title; ?>" class="img-container md img"value="<?php echo $neigborhood_id;?>">
        <img src="<?php echo DOCBASE."medias/hotel/small/".$hotel_file_id."/".$hotel_file; ?>">
      </a>
    </li>
```

ok, i got the id of neiborhood, with the 3,4 lines, then i need to assign that value to another id, for later make a if loop which will hide or show some img depending of which link was clicked.

here is an img to try to explain what i need.

[image: What I want]

sorry for my english, and im a bit noob programming :(

Comment: Can you also include the relevant HTML please?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing with `val` and what is the DOM architecture you have. Can you add a sample of your HTML code?

Comment: Can you add relevant HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign id like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.neigborhood').click(function() {
    var neigborhood_child = $(this).children();
    var neigborhood_id = $(neigborhood_child).val();

    // assign neigborhood_id to ".img" element 
    $('.img').attr('id', neigborhood_id );
    });
});
```

**Note :** But its recommended that id should be always unique on the page.

Comment: "Recommended" is an understatement

Answer (score 0):

Never use same ID for different elements. For hiding the IMG you don't need ID. Just use `next()` function with `this`.

```
$('.neigborhood').click(function() {
    $(this).next('li').toggle();
});
```